# Extracting several values out of list in python

Tags: python, for-loop, annotations

I had a dictionary which I transformed as a list from a dictionary and my task is to create product lists based on their tag however I keep getting an empty list:

That's my list (values_list):

```
[['lipstick', 'spray', 'polish', 'other'],
 [{'annotated_regions': [{'tags': ['lipstick'],
     'region_type': 'Box',
     'region': {'xmin': 0.6413427734375,
      'ymin': 0.2342342380079588015,
      'xmax': 0.234234230703125,
      'ymax': 0.4645647705992509}},
    {'tags': ['polish'],
     'region_type': 'Box',
     'region': {'xmin': 0.234234334375,
      'ymin': 0.234234224531835,
      'xmax': 0.4564560546875,
      'ymax': 0.2342341481741573}},
    {'tags': ['lipstick'],
     'region_type': 'Box'
```

My for loop:

```
lipstick_tag = []
for idx, item in enumerate(values_list):
    if 'tags' == 'lipstick':
        lipstick_tag.append(item)
```

Comment: `if 'tags' == 'lipstick'` is always False, just like `if 0 == 1` is always False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is expecting the data to be in a very different format from your `values_list`. Try this instead

`[item for item in values_list[1][0]['annotated_regions'] if 'lipstick' in item['tags']]`

Comment: thank you a lot! I forgot the indexing as well :(